Incorrect macro calculations with Bing API key: Correct distance from 36088 to 10117, but incorrect back calculation
I have a problem with my macros that use a Bing API key to calculate the distance  between  the postal codes 36088 and 10117. The calculation from 36088 to 10117 (436.809 km) is correct, but the reverse distance from 10117 to 36088 (43.466 km) is incorrect. I have already researched thoroughly, but found no solution or error. (PS: These are German postal codes). I only have a problem with zip code 36088.enter image description here (https://i.sstatic.net/SXX3R.jpg)
I need help, please.
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String) As String
Dim myKey As String: myKey = "APIKEY BING"
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim regex As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim coordinates1 As String
Dim coordinates2 As String
Dim distance As Double
Dim result As String

    ' Erstellen einer HTTP-Anforderung
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    
    ' Abrufen der Koordinaten für den Startpunkt
    objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=" & start & "&key=" & myKey, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    
    ' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "coordinates") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    
    ' Extrahieren der Koordinaten aus der Antwort
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "(?=.*)\[([0-9]+.[0-9]+,[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\]": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    coordinates1 = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    
    ' Abrufen der Koordinaten für das Ziel
    objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=" & dest & "&key=" & myKey, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    
    ' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "coordinates") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    
    ' Extrahieren der Koordinaten aus der Antwort
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "(?=.*)\[([0-9]+.[0-9]+,[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\]": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    coordinates2 = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    
    ' Abrufen der Entfernung zwischen den beiden Koordinaten
    objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=" & coordinates1 & "&destinations=" & coordinates2 & "&travelMode=driving&distanceUnit=km&output=json&key=" & myKey, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    
    ' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "travelDistance") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    
    ' Extrahieren der Entfernung aus der Antwort und Runden auf drei Dezimalstellen
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)": regex.Global = True
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    distance = CDbl(matches(4)) / 1000 'nachkommerstellen
    
    ' Konvertieren der Entfernung in einen String mit der Einheit "Km"
    'result = Format(distance, "0.00") & " Km"
    
    ' Rückgabe des Ergebnisses
    GetDistance = distance
    Exit Function

ErrorHandl:
' Anzeigen einer Fehlermeldung, wenn ein Fehler auftritt
MsgBox (objHTTP.responseText), vbCritical, "ERROR"
GetDistance = "Fehler"
End Function


Please fix the code block so all code is inside the block. Question: Can you include the entire objHTTP.responseText string, for both directions?

What do you meen with both directions? it should calculate for both direction with this code. Or not?

I want to see what the system returns, both for the 'von start nach dest' and for the 'von dest nach start'.

i have solved my problem. i calculate in both directions and take both results. i then output the higher value of the results as the distance.
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String) As String
Dim myKey As String: myKey = "AktGqTbEKPkzO_bXbZqKJgYM80CmGhHac1Ox2ybn0SJ4xE6nHJX9cLDIrIXNnOAQ"
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim regex As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim coordinates1 As String
Dim coordinates2 As String
Dim distance1 As Double
Dim distance2 As Double
Dim result As String

' Erstellen einer HTTP-Anforderung
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

' Abrufen der Koordinaten für den Startpunkt
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=" & start & "&key=" & myKey, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")

' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "coordinates") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

' Extrahieren der Koordinaten aus der Antwort
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "(?=.*)\[([0-9]+.[0-9]+,[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\]": regex.Global = False
Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
coordinates1 = matches(0).SubMatches(0)

' Abrufen der Koordinaten für das Ziel
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=" & dest & "&key=" & myKey, False
objHTTP.send ("")

' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "coordinates") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

' Extrahieren der Koordinaten aus der Antwort
Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
coordinates2 = matches(0).SubMatches(0)

' Abrufen der Entfernung zwischen den beiden Koordinaten (von start nach dest)
objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=" & coordinates1 & "&destinations=" & coordinates2 & "&travelMode=driving&distanceUnit=km&output=json&key=" & myKey, False
objHTTP.send ("")

' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "travelDistance") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

' Extrahieren der Entfernung aus der Antwort und Runden auf drei Dezimalstellen
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)": regex.Global = True
Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
distance1 = CDbl(matches(4)) / 1000 'nachkommerstellen

' Abrufen der Entfernung zwischen den beiden Koordinaten (von dest nach start)
objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=" & coordinates2 & "&destinations=" & coordinates1 & "&travelMode=driving&distanceUnit=km&output=json&key=" & myKey, False
objHTTP.send ("")

' Überprüfen, ob die Antwort gültig ist
If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "travelDistance") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

' Extrahieren der Entfernung aus der Antwort und Runden auf drei Dezimalstellen
Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
distance2 = CDbl(matches(4)) / 1000 'nachkommerstellen

' Vergleichen der Entfernungen und Auswahl des größeren Werts
If distance1 >= distance2 Then
    result = distance1
Else
    result = distance2
End If

' Rückgabe des Ergebnisses
GetDistance = result
Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
' Anzeigen einer Fehlermeldung, wenn ein Fehler auftritt
MsgBox (objHTTP.responseText), vbCritical, "ERROR"
GetDistance = "Fehler" 
End Function

